# Ios enrollment programmes

Tags: ios

I have just made my first app for ios and concluded the necessary testing.

Before i proceed with the upload in order to get the approval of Apple i want to ask:

I am a third party developer hired from a company to make this app.i want this app not to be public and just distribute to specific employees of the company. Can anyone explain me in few words the procudure i should follow. I mean which program enrollment should i use and the steps me and the company should make.

The apple guide is too confusing so i need an answer from an expirienced ios developer in order to make the right decision

Comment: Voting to close as not about programming, but there's no danger at all in sending the app to Apple.  The process is (1) send to apple (2) in iTunes connect, see the test flight tab to test with testers you select, (3) submit for review, (4) the app won't be released until after approval (and you can request to manually release it after approval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 options. You can enroll in the Apple Developer Enterprise if it's one large corporation:
https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Or a generally easier option is via here:
https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

*"Select the custom B2B distribution option in iTunes Connect. If your app contains sensitive data, provide sample data and authentication for our review team."*